# Using same entities for multiple DBs spring boot hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

I have a set of entities and corresponding tables in DB1. There is a parent entity - Parent, which has child entities in it with some relationship owned by Parent. 
I save the all entities by just *ParentRepo.save(parent)*.

```
Parent{
    ... columns

    @oneToMany
    ChildEntity1

    @oneToMany
    ChildEntity2
}
```

Now another db - DB2 comes in, its tables are subset of DB1 , lets say tables for only `Parent` and `ChildEntity1` exist in DB2 , with same table names, same columns. Now i want to use same entities (from DB1) for reading/writing to DB2. 
How to do that?

When i do it normaly by just supplying the same package (of DB1 entities) in *packageToScan* in hibernate config, I get error on saving.

When I run *ParentRepoDB2.save(parent)* I get -
`DB2.Child_Entity2 doesnt exist in in database`

I know obviously it doesn't exist. How to ignore such entities from relationship constraints & db considerations?
One approach is to add custom annotation on entities that have table in DB2 and tell hibernate to ignore rest, but don't know how do it.

Any help please!!